# Why my Vagrantfile settings can reach the internet and not the same LAN outside Virtualbox VM?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, lan, ping, vagrant

I can reach the internet and another Virtualbox Vagrant machine (they ping each other) but I can't reach the same range IP of my LAN and the gateway. I tried many settings with private network and bridge, everything but I have no clue how could I get working fine at same LAN.

IP: 192.168.15.1 GW  - IP: 192.168.15.103  HOST

Validation:

```
[root@centos-vm vagrant]# ifconfig | grep 192.
        inet 192.168.15.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
[root@centos-vm vagrant]# ping 192.168.15.102
PING 192.168.15.102 (192.168.15.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.15.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.250 ms
\\\
--- 192.168.15.102 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2033ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.250/0.269/0.300/0.022 ms
[root@centos-vm vagrant]# ping 192.168.15.1
PING 192.168.15.1 (192.168.15.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.15.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1000ms

[root@centos-vm vagrant]# ping 192.168.15.103
PING 192.168.15.103 (192.168.15.103) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.15.103 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2000ms 

root@debian-vm:/home/vagrant# ping 192.168.15.100
PING 192.168.15.100 (192.168.15.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.15.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.382 ms
```

Vagranfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.gui = false
     vb.memory = "4096"
     vb.cpus = "4"
end
  config.vm.define "vm1" do |vm1|
      vm1.vm.box = "centos/7"
      vm1.vm.hostname = "centos-vm"
      vm1.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.15.100"
      vm1.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
         route add default gw 192.168.15.1
         #removed
         sudo yum update
      SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "vm2" do |vm2|
      vm2.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
      vm2.vm.hostname = "debian-vm"
      vm2.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.15.102"
      vm2.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
         route add default gw 192.168.15.1
         ##removed
         sudo apt update
      SHELL
  end
end
```

Tried before in this way but did not work fine, just do the same results.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.gui = false
     vb.memory = "4096"
     vb.cpus = "4"
  end
  config.vm.define "vm1" do |vm1|
      vm1.vm.box = "centos/7"
      vm1.vm.hostname = "centos-vm"
      vm1.vm.network "private_network", auto_config: "false", virtualbox__intnet: "true", ip: "192.168.15.142"
      vm1.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
         sudo yum update
      SHELL
  end
  config.vm.define "vm2" do |vm2|
      vm2.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
      vm2.vm.hostname = "debian-vm"
      vm2.vm.network "private_network"
      vm2.vm.network "private_network", auto_config: "false", virtualbox__intnet: "true", ip: "192.168.15.142"
      vm2.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
         sudo apt-get update
      SHELL
  end
end
```

Vboxmanage list vms:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
λ vboxmanage showvminfo pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603
Name:                        pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603
Groups:                      /
Guest OS:                    Red Hat (64-bit)
UUID:                        4a54f8b2-13b2-4160-80da-79648c538363
Config file:                 C:\Users\Marlon\VirtualBox VMs\pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603\pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603.vbox
Snapshot folder:             C:\Users\Marlon\VirtualBox VMs\pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603\Snapshots
Log folder:                  C:\Users\Marlon\VirtualBox VMs\pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603\Logs
Hardware UUID:               4a54f8b2-13b2-4160-80da-79648c538363
Memory size                  4096MB
Page Fusion:                 disabled
VRAM size:                   16MB
CPU exec cap:                100%
HPET:                        disabled
CPUProfile:                  host
Chipset:                     piix3
Firmware:                    BIOS
Number of CPUs:              4
PAE:                         enabled
Long Mode:                   enabled
Triple Fault Reset:          disabled
APIC:                        enabled
X2APIC:                      enabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-V:           disabled
CPUID Portability Level:     0
CPUID overrides:             None
Boot menu mode:              message and menu
Boot Device 1:               Floppy
Boot Device 2:               DVD
Boot Device 3:               HardDisk
Boot Device 4:               Not Assigned
ACPI:                        enabled
IOAPIC:                      enabled
BIOS APIC mode:              APIC
Time offset:                 0ms
RTC:                         UTC
Hardw. virt.ext:             enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 enabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x unr. exec.:             enabled
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   KVM
State:                       running (since 2019-09-30T15:26:49.514000000)
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             disabled
2D Video Acceleration:       disabled
Teleporter Enabled:          disabled
Teleporter Port:             0
Teleporter Address:
Teleporter Password:
Tracing Enabled:             disabled
Allow Tracing to Access VM:  disabled
Tracing Configuration:
Autostart Enabled:           disabled
Autostart Delay:             0
Default Frontend:
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
Storage Controller Type (0):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
IDE (0, 0): C:\Users\Marlon\VirtualBox VMs\pipeline_vm1_1569857197240_90603\centos-7-1-1.x86_64.vmdk (UUID: b753eb58-3af1-4af6-b894-36e7546038d3)
NIC 1:                       MAC: 5254008AFEE6, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 2222, guest ip = , guest port = 22
NIC 2:                       MAC: 0800274B37C2, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 3:                       disabled
NIC 4:                       disabled
NIC 5:                       disabled
NIC 6:                       disabled
NIC 7:                       disabled
NIC 8:                       disabled
Pointing Device:             PS/2 Mouse
Keyboard Device:             PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:                      disabled
UART 2:                      disabled
UART 3:                      disabled
UART 4:                      disabled
LPT 1:                       disabled
LPT 2:                       disabled
Audio:                       enabled (Driver: DSOUND, Controller: AC97, Codec: STAC9700)
Audio playback:              disabled
Audio capture:               disabled
Clipboard Mode:              disabled
Drag and drop Mode:          disabled
Session name:                headless
Video mode:                  720x400x0 at 0,0 enabled
VRDE:                        disabled
OHCI USB:                    disabled
EHCI USB:                    disabled
xHCI USB:                    disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Available remote USB devices:

<none>

Currently Attached USB Devices:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:<none>

VRDE Connection:             not active
Clients so far:              0

Capturing:                   not active
Capture audio:               not active
Capture screens:
Capture file:                C:\Users\Marlon\VirtualBox VMs\centos-7-1-1.x86_64_1569857189085_60778\centos-7-1-1.x86_64_1569857189085_60778.webm
Capture dimensions:          1024x768
Capture rate:                512kbps
Capture FPS:                 25kbps
Capture options:

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size: 0MB
OS type:                     RedHat_64
Additions run level:         0

Guest Facilities:

No active facilities.
```

Comment: Please share more information - What is the IP range of your local network? What is the IP range of VirtualBox's internal network? What is the output of `vboxmanage showvminfo ${VM}`? It _looks_ like VirtualBox's internal network has is configured for an IP range that conflicts with your physical network...

Comment: @Attie The network range is 192.168.15.2 - 192.168.15.200 of my LAN. About the VirtualBox I really don't know if you can define a IP range. The output of vboxmanage I edit and put last lines on the text body. The install of Virtualbox was with chocolatey (choco install virtuabox).

Comment: Did for the 1st VM.Body text support just 30000 word count. @Attie

Comment: @Attie I noticed that in the host manager of VirtualBox there was two ranges. So I put on the range that cable is connected at the same range that my router is working. So I will try to see what happens...Do you have any clue about the range on Virtualbox host manager?

Comment: @Attie Now thins are going right...If you could vote on  my post to help the community will be appreciate. Tks for helping me and get in the right way!

Comment: sorry for not responding, I've been busy... well done for getting it working though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some fix and changed my Vagranfile and worked fine ping my gateway and my Host at same LAN!!
Changed VirtualBox - Host Netkork Manager to reflect the same range and configuration of my router IP range and gw too...

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.gui = false
     vb.memory = "4096"
     vb.cpus = "4"
  end
  config.vm.define "centos7" do |centos7|
      centos7.vm.box = "centos/7"
      centos7.vm.hostname = "centos-vm"
      centos7.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.15.100"
      centos7.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
         sudo yum update
         sudo yum -y install wget ntpdate net-tools nano firewalld jenkins apache
         sudo route add default gw 192.168.15.1
         # Install jenkins
         sudo yum -y install epel-release
         sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
         java -version
         sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
         sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
         sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
         sudo yum -y install jenkins
         sudo systemctl start jenkins
         sudo systemctl enable --now jenkins
         sudo systemctl status jenkins
         # Install docker
         curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
         sudo systemctl start docker
         sudo systemctl status docker
         sudo systemctl enable docker
         sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
         sudo ps -ef | grep dockerd
      SHELL
  end
  config.vm.define "debian10" do |debian10|
      debian10.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
      debian10.vm.hostname = "debian-vm"
      debian10.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.15.102"
      debian10.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
         sudo apt update
         sudo apt install wget ntpdate net-tools nano -y
         sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common -y
         sudo route add default gw 192.168.15.1
         curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
         sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
         sudo apt update
         apt-cache policy docker-ce
         sudo apt install docker-ce -y
         sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
         sudo systemctl status docker
         sudo systemctl enable docker
         sudo ps -ef | grep dockerd
      SHELL
  end
end
```